# ASP.NET Entity Framework SqlQuery not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an SQL query, when I run it in the SQL Server, it works fine as expected. Now I want to use this query with Entity Framework like so:

```
ViewBag.TimeSlots = dbTimeSlots.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT a.id, concat(a.dateSlot, ' - ', a.timeSlot) as dateTimeSlot, sum(IIF(b.dateSlot is null,0,1)) as counter FROM VIP_Preview_TimeSlots as a LEFT OUTER JOIN [CP-VIP-Preview] as b ON a.dateSlot = b.dateSlot AND a.timeSlot = b.timeSlot GROUP BY a.timeSlot, a.dateSlot, a.[order], a.id Having sum(IIF(b.dateSlot is null,0,1)) < 30 ORDER BY a.[order]").ToList();
```

However when I run it, I get this error:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified ‘CP.Models.VIP_Preview_TimeSlots'. A member of the type, 'timeSlot', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

Here is my class:

```
public class VIP_Preview_TimeSlots
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Time Slots")]
        public string timeSlot { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Date Slots")]
        public string dateSlot { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
    }

    public class VIPPreviewTimeSlots : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<VIP_Preview_TimeSlots> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

I really dont know why this is not working, the query works, I dont know why Entity Framework has an issue with it, how can I fix this?

Even when I try a simple Query:

```
ViewBag.TimeSlots = dbTimeSlots.Data.SqlQuery("SELECT id, concat(dateSlot, ' - ', timeSlot) as dateTimeSlot FROM VIP_Preview_TimeSlots").ToList();
```

I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query doesn't return `dateSlot` and `timeSlot` as individual columns, but rather concatenates them to `dateSlot + ' - ' + timeSlot` as `dateTimeSlot`.

Adjust your SQL Query from

```
concat(a.dateSlot, ' - ', a.timeSlot) as dateTimeSlot
```

to:

```
a.dateSlot, a.timeSlot
```

**or**

Remove your `timeSlot` and `dateSlot` properties and replace them with a `dateTimeSlot` property.

Comment: If so, then that is your error, entity framework is looking for `timeSlot` and `dateSlot`, not `dateTimeSlot`

Answer (score 0):

You have `id`, `dateTimeSlot` and `counter` as columns returned by the query, no `timeSlot`.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework code is looking for a timeslot property, which seems missing in your select query.